# I can't see my app in beta distribution

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have my app in beta distribution, but I don't have a production apk yet.

I already configured the google group with the tester and they have accepted the invitation of beta testers.

It's something weird If I write the url of google play with my app. Google play shows me the app but I can't search the app with the searcher of google play.

Someone know why I can't search my app in google play? (I'm beta tester)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beta versions are not searcheable on Google Play. Even if you are one of the beta testers.

Source: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/3055329?hl=en

Comment: I didn't know it. Thanks!